# How to circumvent file transfering restrictions on a usb disabled computer?

Tags: windows, network-shares, file-transfer

No cdroms, no lan cable, no usb slots, only have a ps/2 mouse and ps/2 keyboard.
How can I transfer files from usb hard drive to this computer?

Will a ps/2-to-usb adapter do this ?

**Updated**: Well, I wanna clarify something, when I said 'disabled', meant that they're physically disabled, maybe the usb slot didn't  connect to mainboard, but I don't know how they did this, we're using a dell cases that has a password lock.
And one information I wanna to share is, I try to use PCMCIA to USB Adapter to connect usb hard drive to my laptop, doesn't work.

Comment: Are the cdrom usb etc disabled via software settings or are they physically gone? If its software I might be able to help you with re-enabling usb...

Comment: physically gone

Comment: Can you clarify the network connectivity?  In the question you say no network cable, but in comments below you say it has "lan access" to port 80.   Can you access local web servers?   Internet web servers?

Comment: Actually I can connect to internet, only 80 port is open, but transfer from cable is impossible,the file need to transfer is really huge, and the connection is rather slow. so I assumed that there's no cable.

Answer (score 7):

Not to be a wet blanket, but it sounds like whomever owns the computer in question does not want any one to transfer files to or from it.  Your best bet is to contact the person(s) responsible for the system and find out what options you have, if any.  IANAL, but if they tell you that you are not allowed to transfer files and you do so, you could find yourself with legal issues.

**Update based on Tony's comment**

@Tony - If it is the case that you can connect to the internet (with a slow connection) and desire to transfer a large file then you do need to contact the person(s) responsible for the computer.  They are the only ones that will be able to help you get your file.  They may be able to help determine why the connection is slow and, possibly, boost the speed.  The computer's admins may have other ways of moving the file for you.  They'll also be able to tell you whether or not transferring the file falls within the Acceptable Use Policy for that computer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think a PS/2 to USB adapter will work.
Are the USB plugs disabled, plugged, or non-existant?  Can't remember the last time I saw a PC without a USB socket.  If they are disabled/or plugged,  there's probably a reason, and you need to talk to whoever is in charge of maintaining the PC.

Comment: Definitely not.  The PS/2 to USB adapter simulates a Human interface Device and only allows a keyboard or mouse to be connected.

Comment: @Chris:That's what I was thinking, but you said it much better than I!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to open the case and plug an IDE hard drive into the motherboard.  Barring physical access to the innards or data ports the only way to get data into the machine is via the keyboard.

Comment: the case is locked. No way to open it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most USB hard drives are just 2.5 inch disk in a USB enabled IDE caddy.  You could strip the hard disk out of the caddy and then install it in to the computer.

EDIT:  Though you would also need one of [these](http://www.xvillage999.com/product_info.php?language=en&currency=GBP&products_id=2169) thinking about.  Not as easy as I first thought.  Sorry.

Comment: Note: The 2,5"->3.5" adapter is only for ATA/IDE drives. New drives using Serial ATA (SATA) always have a standard connector.

Answer (score 1):

Tony, in your comment to JRobert you said the computer has LAN and port 80 is open, so here is an easy solution:

1. Using another computer, put your files on a web server you own, or on a public file sharing website.
2. Then just download the files from the Dell computer. (FTP is not needed)

Of course, the best would be to explain your need to the computer's admin, so that he/she removes the protection.

Answer (score 0):

Broadband access to another computer into which your drive is plugged, and access the files via LAN, FTP, LogMeIn, etc.

Comment: The question says "no USB, no lan". That would probably make it impossible to connect to broadband (OK, maybe WLAN).

Comment: yes, actually, it has lan. but only 80 port is opened. So no ftp.

Comment: OK in the same vein as above, here are a couple more ideas: 
* Host your files on a server that will serve them over http[s].
* Host them yourself temporarily, with HFS File Server ( http://www.rejetto.com/hfs/ ); runs in Windows & Wine/Linux and serves over a port of your choosing.
* Carry them to the isolated computer in a laptop or Ethernet External Hard Drive and transfer them over Ethernet / Windows File Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If USB/CDROM are disabled in the OS and not the BIOS you can boot with a livecd and copy files over.  If disabled in the BIOS, and BIOS is password protected, you would need to clear the BIOS password which involves opening up the computer.

Edit - since CDROM is removed, try a bootable USB drive with the other bios info applicable.

Comment: They removed the cdrom from the computer.LOL

Comment: According to the question there aren't any USB ports either.

Answer (score 0):

Take the hard drive out of this system.  Connect it up to another system, using IDE/SATA/USB caddy etc.

Transfer and edit files as needed.

Return hard-drive to original system.

Answer (score 0):

ps/2-to-usb adapter will not work to transfer data in. as the PS/2 port is only for Mouse and Keyboard connections. connecting other types of usb devices to it will not work.

I would also agree with those who say make sure it's okay with the owner what your trying to accomplish first or you could end up in a lot of trouble

now if it's a desktop and you got accesses to the inside of the case you could bring a cdrom drive from another computer or take the drive out of this one and sick it in another and copy the files over.

if you don't got that kind of access, and only one port is open FTP won't work even if you change the port as ftp uses two ports, one for commands one for data. Windows File share won't work if your stuck with port 80 as it uses a range of other ports and trying to change those is messy at best. so putting them on a http server is your best bet.  if you got one that you can connect on the same lan segment, then unless the bottleneck is on the card itself you should get better speeds then normal as if the server it's trying to get to is on the same part of the LAN it is, then it doesn't bother with the internet connection it connect directly to it; therefor is able to go as fast as the lan or nic settings allow (which ever is slower unfortunately) there are several free and easy to setup web servers one I use is called "Baby Web Server"